# Can anyone explain to me the manipulation used in this answer?

Tags: integration

\begin{align}
\mathbf{4.} \quad \int \frac {1+x^2\ln x} {x(1+x\ln x)} \,\Bbb dx &= \int \left( \frac {1+x} x -\frac {1+\ln x} {1+x\ln x} \right) \Bbb dx \\ &= \int \left( \frac1x+1 \right) \Bbb dx +\int \frac {(1+x\ln x)'} {1+x\ln x} \,\Bbb dx \\ &= \ln x +x -\ln|1+x\ln x| +C
\end{align}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First row: decomposition in partial fractions. Also, I know I transcripted the image, but the sign outside the second integral changes wrongfully to plus at the second row.